# Where to find the jre location in jdk 16 version

Tags: java-16

[image: JDK 16 location]

This might be a really basic question however I'm new to java. I need to set the ClassPath variable to the JRE folder which supposes to be inside JDK 16 folder. I don't see the folder name 'JRE'. Am I missing anything? Or setting classpath up to jdk 16 is fine?

Comment: JDK Installer says "including a private JRE and src.zip".  Is this different JRE than regular JRE in an earlier version of java?

Comment: You can create a JRE yourself using `jlink`

Comment: There is no JRE folder anymore, removing a lot of redundancy found in older versions. Whether setting your variable to the JDK is fine, depends on why you have to set the variable at all. It’s not clear what “the ClassPath variable” is supposed to be.

Comment: There's no JRE since JDK 11 - see JDK 11 migration guide:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/migrate/index.html#JSMIG-GUID-561005C1-12BB-455C-AD41-00455CAD23A6